# MVC3 Partial View - Is it better Ajax.BeginForm or Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Partial View with two opposite ActionLinks inside:

```
    <div id="divStatus>  
    @if (IsAuthenticated) 
        Html.ActionLink("Say Bye", "ProcBye", "Account")
    else 
        Html.ActionLink("Say Hi", "ProcHi", "Account")
    </div>
```

Each Action link calls a different method on the Controller.

I hear I should use **Ajax.BeginForm** but I'm still NOT clear how to put this?
My understanding is that I need a **`<div id="divStatus">`** to display the result, but in my case ...the result is the Partial View itself.

**QUESTION:**  How do I ensure make it so the Controller **just** refreshes the calling Partial View??

Shall I just add a **div outside** the PV?
Shall I add the **div inside** the PV **surrounding** the '@if (IsAuthenticate)' call?
Is it better to use **Ajax.BeginForm** or **Ajax.ActionLink** in this case?

**CODE:** What should the code for the Controller look like?

```
    public ActionResult ProcBye()
    {
        // do something on the server
        // set IsAuthenticated = false;

        return PartialView("_myPV");
    }
```

---

There is NO Validation Involved, NO "external" div that needs to be populated, just a simple refresh of the PV independently from what page the PV is located.

Any help will be truly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use neither. I would use a separate javascript file in which I would AJAXify the link:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mylink').click(function() {
        $('#resultdiv').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

where resultdiv will be a div which will be update with the partial result returned from the controller action:

```
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
```

You just need to put the `mylink` class:

```
@if (IsAuthenticated) 
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Say Bye", "ProcBye", "Account", null, new { @class = "mylink" })
}
else 
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Say Hi", "ProcHi", "Account", null, new { @class = "mylink" })
}
```

You could also use `Ajax.ActionLink` if you wanted to:

```
@if (IsAuthenticated) 
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Say Bye", "ProcBye", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultdiv" })
}
else 
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Say Hi", "ProcHi", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultdiv" })
}
```

Just don't forget to include the jquery unobtrusive ajax script in this case:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your 1st approach.  

1) I added the reference to the unobstrusive ajax script
2) I added the script function call (as <script> on the top of the PV itself instead of on a separate file)
3) I added the "new { @class = "mylink" }" to the 2 links

the resulting <a> tags looks like this:  
<a class="mylink" href="/Home/ProcBye?Length=7">Say Bye</a>


Any thoughts ?

Comment: the <script> tag was added as **<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">**

Comment: @Filu, that's because I made a mistake in my post and was using the wrong overload of the `Html.ActionLink` helper. There is another parameter which represent the `routeValues` just after the controller name which I've specified to null. I've updated my answer to fix this. Also your script tag should look like this: `<script type="text/javascript">`, no `language` attribute.